# Printing a 2D Character Array - Last input cut off

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, conways-game-of-life

I'm making the game of life in which the user specifies the dimensions of the grid, and then inputs the data to fill the grid.

X= Live

. = Dead

The problem with my current code is if the user say wants a 3x3 grid (9 values), when printing the grid, 8 are output. I've tried changing the conditions to <=, or starting the loops with -1 but this doesn't seem to work

I've used loops i've seen on other posts such as: [Printing a 2D array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741784/printing-a-2d-array-in-c) but the problem still persists.

Heres the code:

```
int WIDTH, HEIGHT, CYCLES;
scanf("%d %d %d",&WIDTH,&HEIGHT,&CYCLES);

//Grids
char grid[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
char temp[HEIGHT][WIDTH];

//Columns + Rows
for (int row = 0; row <HEIGHT ; ++row)
{
    for (int col = 0; col <WIDTH ; ++col)
    {
        scanf("%c",&grid[row][col]);
    }
}

for (int row = 0; row <HEIGHT ; ++row)
{
    for (int col = 0; col <WIDTH ; ++col)
    {
        printf("%c",grid[row][col]);
    }
}
```

Appareciate any help

Comment: As a last statement, add `printf("\n");` so you are sure the output buffer is flushed.

Comment: How are you inputting your rows, if you're doing one row with each entry, the carriage return of each row will be soaked up as one of the cells because you're not skipping whitespace on your iterations. `" %c"` for the format string, you would dodge that (space before `%c` in the string).

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks, adding the space meant the array printed correctly with nothing cut off at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing

```
scanf("%c",&grid[row][col]);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c",&grid[row][col]);
```

**Adding a Space** before %c fixed this. Cheers to @WhozCraig