# How to convert number to a star symbol?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I want to write a simple application that writes 3 numbers into an array. The numbers should be read in from the keyboard with scanf.
The following should be displayed on the screen:
If the entered numbers are 1,5,4, the following will be displayed

```
*
*****
****
```

My problem stays only in,how to convert number to a star symbol.Thank you!

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
    printf("%d ",i);
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: you could allocate an array of size n and then fill it with star characters, followed by 0-terminated string, then print a string.  the first one can be done using memset function. There is an example here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memset.htm

Comment: You haven't explained what's wrong with your code.

Comment: where is the user input from `scanf`? This must be incorporated into your loops

Comment: Did you forget to read in user input? If so, you might be interested in [scanf function family](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing a 2D array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741784/printing-a-2d-array-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take this written in javascript, you should be able to convert it in C for your project :)

The loops are the key, one to scan each element of the input array, and another to print as many `*` as the value of the array (1, 5 and 4)

```js
var input = [1, 5, 4]; // Let's assume you already have the input array
var output = ""; // You don't need this

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < input[i]; j++) {
    output += "*"; // printf("*");
  }
  output += "\n"; // printf("\n");
}

console.log(output); // You don't need this
```

Comment: it is not C for sure

Comment: Have you ever heard of `pseudocode`? You can show how the loop logic has to be set up, then you can write it in your language. I also added some comments, it shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

I have two versions. Version 1 is easier and Version 2 is likely more efficient.

Basic version: allocate a string, fill it with N stars and print it.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

void printNstars(int N)
{
    char* str = (char *) malloc (N+1);
    memset(str,'*',N);
    str[N] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

A more efficient version would be to allocate the array once, and then reuse it. Here is an example. Note, that you need to handle cases with number more than 50.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

char str[50];

void initStr() {
    memset(str,'*',51);
    // so that one can use printf("%s", str), needed to handle cases N > 50
    str[50] = '\0';
}

void printNstars(int N) 
{
    //handle N > 50, print whole array N div 50 times
    while (N > 50) {
        printf("%s", str); 
        N -= 50;
    }
    
    str[N] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", str);   
    str[N] = '*';
}

int main()
{
    initStr();
    printNstars(5);
    printNstars(15);
    printNstars(3);    

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void printArray(int *arr, size_t size)
{
    while(size--)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < *arr; i++) printf("*");
        arr++;
        printf("\n");
    }
}

#define  NNUMBERS   3

int main(void)
{
    int arr[NNUMBERS];

    for(int i = 0; i < NNUMBERS; i++)
    {
        do
        {
            printf("\nEnter %d number:", i); 
        }while(scanf(" %d", &arr[i]) != 1);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printArray(arr,NNUMBERS);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/K63cfrx88